# Showing that Greedy algorithm exhibits optimal substructure and greedy choice

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, computer-science, greedy

I am in need of help proving that an algorithm has greedy choice property and optimal substructure.

**Context of the problem:**

Consider a problem where a company owns `n` gas stations that  are connected by a highway.
Each gas station has a limited supply `g_i` of gas-cans. Since the company don't know which gas station is most visited they want all of them to have the same amount of gas.

So they hire a fueling-truck to haul gas between the stations in their truck. However, truck also consumes 1 gas-can per kilometer driven.

Your task will be to help the chain calculate the largest amount of gas-cans `g_bar`
they can have at all Stations.

Consider the example: Here we have g = (20, 40, 80, 10, 20) and
p = (0, 5, 13, 33, 36) (in kilometers). In order to send one gas-can from station 3 to
station 4 we need to put 41 gas-cans in the truck, as the fueling-truck will consume 40 before reaching their destination (to send two gas-cans we need to put 42 in the truck).
The optimal `g_bar` for the example is 21 and can be achieved as follows:

1. Station 2 sends 11 gas-cans towards Station 1. One gas-can arrives while ten are consumed on the way.
2. Station 3 sends 59 gas-cans towards Station 4. 19 arrive while 40 are consumed on the way.
3. Station 4 now has 29 gas-cans and send eight towards Station 5. Two of these arrive
   and six are consumed on the way.
4. The final distribution of gas-cans is: (21, 29, 21, 21, 22).

Given an integer  `g_bar`. Determine whether it is possible to get at least  `g_bar` gas-cans in every Gas Station.

*in order for the greedy choice property and optimal substructure to make sense for a decision problem, you can define an optimal solution to be a solution with at least `g_bar` gas-cans in every gas station if such a solution exists; otherwise, any solution is an optimal solution.*

**Input:** The position `p_i` and gas-can supply `g_i of` each bar. Here `g_i` is the supply for the bar at position `p_i`. You may assume that the positions are in sorted order – i.e. `p_1 < p_2 < . . . < p_n`.

**Output:** The largest amount `g_bar`, such that each gas-station can have a gas-can supply of at least `g_bar` after the truck have transferred gas-cans between the stations.

How can i prove Greedy Choice and Optimal Substructure for this?

Comment: The function you’ve added checks if a value of `fBar` Is possible or not. But how are you checking all values of `fBar`? Where are you trying to prove optimal greedy choice?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur im trying to prove that the algorithm has the greedy choice property. I just dont know where to start when its decision based algorithm

Comment: Greedy choice and optimal substructure are properties of *problems*, not of algorithms. Also, this doesn't seem like a greedy algorithm. There's no obvious way to find subproblems that are optimally solved by an optimal solution to the original problem in your algorithm.

Comment: @kcsquared I got told that : "in order for the greedy choice property and optimal substructure to make sense for a decision problem, you can define an optimal solution to be a solution with at least  g_bar gas-cans in every gas station if such a solution exists; otherwise,any solution is an optimal solution." 


i got told that its greedy because every iteration it exchanges gas cans between station i and station i+1, using the iCanSpare variable.

Comment: @kcsquared also we should consider the gas-stations in increasing order (left to right in for gas-station i < n, either it needs gas-cans from gas-station i + 1 or it may have a surplus of gas-cans for gas-station i + 1.

Comment: @kcsquared i added even more info now to the original post, not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define an optimal solution: Each station has at least `X` gas cans in each station (`X` = `g_bar`).

**Proving greedy property**

Let us assume our solution is sub-optimal. There must exist a station `i` such that `gas[i]` < `X`. Based on our algorithm, we borrow `X - gas[i]` from station `i+1` (which is a valid move, since we had already found a solution). Now station `i` has `gas = X`. This contradicts the original assumption that there must exist a station `i` such that `gas[i]` < `X`, which means our solution isn't suboptimal. Hence, we prove the optimality.

**Proving optimal substructure**

Assume we have a subset of the stations of size `N'`, and our solution is suboptimal. Again, if the solution is suboptimal, there must exist a station `i` such that `gas[i]` < `X`. You can use the greedy proof again to prove that our solution isn't suboptimal. Since we have optimal solution for each arbitrary subset, we prove that we have optimal substructure.

Comment: i would argue that the algoritm does make a greedy choice starting with the if-statements, this is because we greedily decide to make the first gas-station have atleast ```g_bar``` amount of gas-cans , without caring for future stations. The if statement checks if we have enough already and can spare for a future station and if 
 not then we need to "steal" gas-cans from another station.

Comment: Well actually it modifies the array so we have atleast ```g_bar```amount of gas-cans for every gas station in the array.  In the algorithm i just returned 0 or 1 but we could have returned the modified array  which if we used the example from earlier in my original question:  Gas = (20, 40, 80, 10, 20) and  Pos = (0, 5, 13, 33, 36) , which would return something like (21, 29, 21, 21, 22).

Comment: @MarcusF why do you need to modify the array? Since you're just checking if a value is possible or not, there's no point in modifying the array

Comment: "Why" i do that is not the point of my original question. Lets say that i needed to create a new array where every station has at least ```g_bar``` gas-cans , and not just check if could or not, it doesn't matter! The algorithm takes a greedy choice regardless and i need to prove it using the greedy choice property.